# Wordpress : Write arabic text type in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, encoding, arabic

I'm using the latest version of WordPress, when I try to write in Arabic any post it turns into `u0644u0628u0627u0621u0644u0627u0621u0641u0628`
I've googled the subject and I found out about the character encoding in both the DB and WP, i have to set both of them to the correct value, in DB = utf8-general-ci and in WP UTF-8 and I thought the problem should be resolved but no it's still not, so if anyone can help.

Comment: Do You have arabic locale installed?

Comment: In admin/post editor your text looks normally? Maybe font used in your theme has no arabic characters?

Comment: in post editor i write text in Arabic good but only in this `<textarea class="widefat" name="quiz_answer[]" id="quiz_answer' . $index . '" >' . esc_textarea( trim( $question_answer ) ) . '</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

Open the website and view source, check the meta tag for Content-Type, is it set to utf-8?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

if not utf-8, fix it in the theme header.php file.